# Firing native js event from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway I can use native javascript to fire an event called onmove which is only for IE.
I can get it to work if I do this.

```
document.getElementById("device-module").fireEvent("onmove");
```

This issue here is I don't want to have to pass an id into the custom jquery prototype. I already know what the element is I just need to call javascript native fireEvent on that element. 
Is this possible or do I have to always get the dom element by document.getElementById() before I can use the js native fireEvent method.

```
  $.fn.custom = function() {  

    return this.each(function() {
          var _this = $(this);
         _this.fireEvent("onmove");

        });

};
```

Comment: Why do you need a "native event"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value of the `this` in an `each()` is the DOM element itself. you can directly access it this way. *no need* to wrap again in `$()`

```
return this.each(function() {
    //the value of "this" in here IS the DOM element
    this.fireEvent('onmove');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.fireEvent("onmove");`

`this` already points to the DOM element when using the `each` iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a jQuery object out of your native element?

```
      var _this = $(this);
```

Just use it:

```
      return this.each(function() {
          this.fireEvent("onmove");
      });
```